# access to redux form values

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a react + redux form with 2 comboboxes (a custom component that wraps a redux field). I want that the options of combobox 2 will be changed by the current value of combobox 1.

**How can I access to combobox-1's current value?**

Of course I can save the value aside in an inner state or a variable by using "onChange" method, but is there a direct way to access the form's value?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';


class MyComponent extends Component {

 getOptionsCombobox1 =()=> {
    return [1,2,3,4];
  }
  getOptionsCombobox2 =()=> {
    // if current value of combobox 1 is X, return [ZZZ], else, return [YYY]
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <MyComboboxComponent
              name="combobox1"
              options={this.getOptionsCombobox1()}
            />

          <MyComboboxComponent
              name="combobox2"
              options={this.getOptionsCombobox2()}
          />

      <div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myComponent ',
  }
)(MyComponent );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [formValueSelector](http://redux-form.com/6.6.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/) in order to achieve that.

Your code should look like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class MyComponent extends Component {

 getOptionsCombobox1 =()=> {
    return [1,2,3,4];
  }
  getOptionsCombobox2 =()=> {
    const {combobox1} = this.props;
    // if current value of combobox 1 is X, return [ZZZ], else, return [YYY]
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
          <MyComboboxComponent
              name="combobox1"
              options={this.getOptionsCombobox1()}
            />

          <MyComboboxComponent
              name="combobox2"
              options={this.getOptionsCombobox2()}
          />

      <div>
    );
  }
}

MyComponent = reduxForm({
    form: 'myComponent ',
  }
)(MyComponent );

const selector = formValueSelector('myComponent'); // Create the selector


const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {
      combobox1: selector(state, 'combobox1') 
   }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```